# Spatial adaption of points to polygons

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon

I have a point layer for the cold air flow in specific region. I would like to simplify all the single points to a polygon shape as to be able to join the data with other spatial data.[image] My way is pretty complicated (buffer the points e.g.400m, dissolve, simplify) because I have to extract the single values (orange, blue, light blue) and then do it with all these single values separately. Afterwards there is the need to create differences in order to avoid doubles. I wonder if somebody knows a more convenient way.

Comment: How can your point data not be joined with other data?

Comment: ..we want to define the whole area of e.g. yellow arrows and combine (union) them with other polygones so that we have a defined area with the attributes yellow+nature reserve+arable land + etc...

Comment: frankly, not but it hits my point exactly. I will test it out. Thank you so far and sorry for missing it out.

Comment: I think you maybe want a concave hull (alpha shape) rather than convex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all the points are in the same layer, and they already an attribute with the desired unique values (classes) I would do the following:

1. Create Voronoi polygons for the point layer (this avoids overlapping)
2. Dissolve the polygons using the mentioned attribute to dissolve adjacent polygons of the same class.
3. Run multiple parts to single parts to split the multi-polygons into single part polygons
4. Clip the result to the area of interest

Comment: this is smart, thank you!